# JavaScript xml2js read arrays from each object from xml document

Tags: node.js, xml

I have xml documt with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Conf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Par>
    <CSP>
      <TXT>Duplex</TXT>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </CSP>
    <CSP>
      <TXT>Half</TXT>
      <ID>2</ID>
    </CSP>
  </Par>
  <Req>
    <FirmwareVersion>A1</FirmwareVersion>
    <LoaderVersion>Z1</LoaderVersion>
    <Name>Bonus</Name>
    <Class>Noring</Class>
    <Revision>05</Revision>
  </Req>
</Conf>
```

I want to read every entry from **CSP** and then the **Req**

so far I used this JS on NodeJS

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/conf.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        var jml = (result);
        console.log(jml.Conf);
    });
});
```

which gives me the result:

```
{
  '$': {
    'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    'xmlns:xsd': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  },
  Par: [ { CSP: [Array] } ],
  Req: [
    {
      FirmwareVersion: [Array],
      LoaderVersion: [Array],
      Name: [Array],
      Class: [Array],
      Revision: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am struggling now to go deeper and read out the arrays and loop through. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What issue are you struggling with? Your code just prints the object to the console, there is no loop in there...

Comment: As mentioned, how do I access eac entry of CSP?

Comment: I want to use the values in other functions in my code.

Comment: I know what you want, but I can't see any attempt and/or error. Here's a hint: `console.log()` does not unravel the full object. At a certain nesting depth it will simply print `[Array]` even though the array values are *there*. Try printing from a deeper nesting level to see what I mean.